# Eclipse resources folder with git & Maven

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a git/Maven (if this has something to do with it) project on Eclipse. I need to add a library folder where some files that i need will be stored. This is the tree structure of my project.

[image]

I try to load the files under folders lib and lib2, but with no success. Some of my attempts were

```
System.out.println("PATH"+this.getClass().getResource("lib").getPath());
System.setProperty("org.hyperic.sigar.path",this.getClass().getResource("lib2/file.xxx"));
```

All of them gets me a NullPointerException.
I know that there are a bunch of answers already out there, I think I tried them all, ok most, and this just doesn't work.

**EDIT:**
After Kraal suggestions I changed my project and now it looks like this:
[image]
But i am still getting NullPointerException on

```
System.setProperty("org.hyperic.sigar.path",this.getClass().getResource("Sigar_lib/libsigar-amd64-linux.so").getPath());
```

Comment: Do you need to load native dll's for use with sigar?

Comment: @Stefan, i need to load the *.so files for sigar. I managed to add a static file, but i need it to be portable, so have to access the full list of files

Comment: Is it a web application or a jar library you are trying to build?

Comment: @Stefan a jar, it is going to be used as a library to other applications i have

Answer (score 1):

This is not related at all to git but to your project's structure. Indeed it does not follow the [Maven standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

- Your java classes should be in `src/main/java`
- Your resource files should be `in src/main/resources`

So you have two choices:

- Correct your setup then retry.
- Configure Maven in your pom in order to look in `lib` / `lib2` for resources.

In both cases, you will then to look for resources at the right place. I.e. `file.xxx` will be located in `file.xxx` and not `src/main/resources/file.xxx` (once you define a resources directory, you can search for resources in this directory)

According to your comments, you should really read this post explaining [how to use Maven within Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html). When you plan to work on a Maven project, create a `Maven project` in Eclipse, not a Java project.

Comment: but that layout was created by default from Eclipse. Eclipse doesnt use the standard layout and I should change it myself!? that is strange. I should just create folders under src, right? will try that and see

Comment: if you create a maven project, eclipse won't create this layout... I hope you've created a Maven project in Eclipse if you plan to work on a Maven project.

Comment: I created a java project and then change it to Maven from within Eclipse, and this was the default layout. I tried to correct my layout, i added the two missing folders under src/ but now my project package changed from `elod.msg` to `main.java.elod.msg`. Is this normal, I preferred it the way it was.

Comment: see my last edit and read this post: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
System.setProperty("org.hyperic.sigar.path",this.getClass().getResource("Sigar_lib/libsigar-amd64-linux.so").getPath());
```

always fails, because when the Jar is packed, the directory "Sigar_lib" will be located at the root of the classpath, so change the path to:

```
"/Sigar_lib/libsigar-amd64-linux.so"
```

(leading slash).

But this will also fail, because the native libraries cannot be loaded from within a jar. Your options are, to put the files into an external directory or add them to the classpath of your jar and extract them to the temporary directory when loading.

The best way to integrate the libraries with Maven is to add them as a dependency, see [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gridkit.lab/sigar-lib/1.6.4) and remove the "lib", "lib2" folders.

At runtime the files can be accessed like this:

```
System.out.println("PATH: " + System.class.getResource("/sigar-1.6.4/libsigar-amd64-linux.so").getPath());
```

**Update**

pom.xml should have these lines:

```
    <!-- SIGAR -->

    <!-- Java library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource</groupId>
        <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Native libraries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gridkit.lab</groupId>
        <artifactId>sigar-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Using a maven dependency for the libs would be great! but i still get NPE on the line as you have it

Comment: The pom file was just like yours. But i am still getting a NPE