# using a library file from within jar

Tags: java, eclipse, sigar

This is a follow up of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608473/eclipse-resources-folder-with-git-maven/34610876#34610876)

What I try to do:
I have an eclipse project that uses th Sigar library in order to get the cpu information (among others). In order to do that Sigar needs a library file to work. Each CPU/OS have a different file, all of which are available.I have to pack this into a jar, that other can use my application as a library.

What I did:
added the available library files to my project and can access them like so

```
System.setProperty("org.hyperic.sigar.path",System.class.getResource("/lib").getPath());
System.load(System.class.getResource(getClass().getResource(
    "/lib/libsigar-amd64-linux.so").toString()).getPath());
```

Both of these seems to work if i run my application as a stand alone application.
When i pack it to a jar and try to run it from an other project, it just doesn't work. I cant make it to see the directory or the file.
This is the structure of my project
[image]
I have tried to access the file with any path i could think of, but all returned a NullPointerException.

How can I do this? Using a temp file? I am not sure how i should do this, i would like to load the whole folder and not just one file, since i dont know the hardware/OS of the client application.

Comment: Why not try to use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) it makes handling libraries much easier and building even easier.

Comment: How would Maven solve my problem? can you elaborate?

Comment: do you know what maven is ? If not I will post a more elaborate answer but to be brief it usually allows you to automatically import external dependencies (jars) and builds them into your app in a clean manner. You current way of putting the jar manually into your project is usually a bad idea and can makes development more challenging.

Comment: I know what Maven is, but the problem is not with the jar. Except from the jar, i need to import a folder full of library files, the `.so` files, as seen on the bottom of the attached image. These files I want to access and i cant. It seems that the problem is that when i jar the project, the tree structure is changed

Comment: Do these files have to be in the `java` directory ? Typically files like these may go into a `resources` directory ? so your `elod.tool.msn` would be in `src/main/java` and the `lib` would be in `src/main/resources`. Once these files are in the resource directory you can access them very easily. For example using  [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)

Comment: These files can be stored anywhere on the system. I was just playing with the position of the folder, just to see if there is a place where i can read them from. Will try to add it on the resources dir(think i did but something didnt work out) and will try the `ResourceBundle` you mention. I havent tried that. Will do this, later today, and let you know